# WiPFlash, UIAutomation right click

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I am using [WiPFlash](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/) to automate some testing in a WPF application.

I need the automation to be able to right click on a button and select one of the options from the context menu.

Has any one been able to overcome this problem? 
I'd be happy to try a different framework or approach if someone has had success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel a bit silly answering my own question. But...

After posting a feature request on the WiPFlash website.  I received a reply which confirmed that there is currently no right click feature in WiPFlash.

So I ended up moving on to using [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) this is quite similar in syntax to WiPFlash so I was able to port over all the work I had done up until that point with minimal effort.  White currently has more features than WiPFlash, including drag and right click options.

Comment: Hi, WiPFlash creator here - strangely found this while looking for the functionality to fix your context menu problem ;) Looks like Microsoft UI Automation has no right-click ability or context-menu raising ability at all; you have to use silly user32.dll functionality. That's why I didn't have it. White is a much older library, and, yes, it has more features, so you're probably right to use it instead. I'm leaving this comment here in case anyone else requires the guidance as to which library to use - though I may have fixed the context menu problem by the time they see it...

Comment: ContextMenu problem now fixed in latest snapshot; new release out soon. Thanks, Klee!